# unable to generate pie chart from phpmyadmin

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

i want to create google pie chart with help of getting table from database ...but till now i did not get output ...i have searched several websites..but i did not clarify anything...please check my code and tell

```
<?php

mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('chart');

$sqlquery1="select * from pie_chart";

$sqlresult1=mysql_query($sqlquery1);

$rows=array();

while($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlresult1))
{
    $rows[]=$r;
}
$data= json_encode($rows);
?>
<html>
<head>
 <!--Load the AJAX API -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script      src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

//Load the visualization API and the piechart package
google.load('visualization','1',{'packages':['corechart']});

//Set a callback to run when the google visualization API is loaded
 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawchart);

function drawChart(){
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn("string", "Quarter");
    data.addColumn("number", "Number");

    data.addRows(<?php echo $data ?>); 

    ]); 

 //Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server
 var data=new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

 //Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options
 var chart=new      google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data,{width:400,height:240});
  }

  </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart -->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: What is the error you are receiving? As a side note , when you want data in your Javascript through PHP Tagging you need to use ECHO. So at your "data.addRows(<?php $data ?>); " change it to "data.addRows(<?php echo $data ?>); " cause right now it is not doing anything there.

Comment: i will change that.. but it will show Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\programs\chart2.php on line 12

Comment: You should move away from the mysql driver in PHP cause it has been removed and will be unavailable in PhP 7.0 , check "http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php" and try to change your code according to it. mysql_query will return boolean (false) if it fails , so probably your query is failing and it is not returning any results , hence the warning you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/* Establish the database connection */
 $mysql =mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'chart');
 /* select all the tasks from the table piechart */
 $result = $mysql->query('SELECT * FROM piechart');

 /*
  ---------------------------
  example data: Table (piechart)
  --------------------------
    Task        percent
  job             30
  daily           20
  working         35
  sleep           15       
 */


$rows = array();
$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(

// Labels for your chart, these represent the column titles.
/* 
    note that one column is in "string" format and another one is in "number" format 
    as pie chart only required "numbers" for calculating percentage 
    and string will be used for Slice title
*/
               array('label' => 'task', 'type' => 'string'),
               array('label' => 'percent', 'type' => 'number')
               );

/* Extract the information from $result */
/* associate array are used in above ,so we used foreach loop*/
foreach($result as $r) 
{
  $temp = array();

   // The following line will be used to slice the Pie chart

   $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['task']); 

   // Values of the each slice

   $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['percent']);

   //rows of side title   
   $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
 }
  $table['rows'] = $rows;

  // convert data into JSON format
  $jsonTable = json_encode($table);
  //echo $jsonTable;

 ?>

 <html>
 <head>
<!--Load the Ajax API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

 // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
function drawChart()
{
 // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
 var bar_chart_data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo $jsonTable; ?>);

 var options = {
                title: 'Daily Work log',
                is3D: 'true',//3D effect true
                width: 900,
                height: 500
               };

  // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
  // Do not forget to check your div ID
 var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

 chart.draw(bar_chart_data, options);
}

   </script>
 </head>
           <body>
            <!--this is the div that will hold the pie chart-->
              <div id="chart_div" ></div>
           </body>
        </html>
   </script>
 </head>
```